# How to get the location/filepath of a file opened in Windows programmatically?

Tags: windows, process, path, location, filepath

I am working on a project that needs to extract the location of a file opened in Windows.For example if a Word document is opened, I need to programmatically determine the location of the file which was opened.

I have tried using GetWindowModuleFileName() but that only provides the location where Word is installed.
The other approaches I have already tried out are:

1. Using [Microsoft.Office.Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects) to get the path using word.ActiveDocument.FullName, but it supports only Office files and that too upto Office 2013.
2. [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) utility which provides all the window handles referencing a given process(PID). I need to parse the output provided by this in order to isolate the file path which could be any one handle in the list and it's a difficult task.

I was wondering if there is any alternate approach/es more direct than those which I have mentioned here.

Thank you for your time.

Edit: My program uses Java Native Access(JNA) currently to get the active windows. 
Here is my code:

```
    public synchronized Map<String, Object> getWindowDetails() {

            Map<String, Object> titleProcessIdMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            char[] buffer = new char[Constants.MAX_TITLE_LENGTH * 2];

            //get active window
            WinDef.HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();

            //get rectangle structure of active window  
            WinDef.RECT rect = new WinDef.RECT();                
            User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(hwnd, rect); 

            //get active window title       
            User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer, Constants.MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
            String windowTitle = Native.toString(buffer).replaceAll("\'", "\\\'");

            //get process Id of active window
            IntByReference pointer = new IntByReference();                
            User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pointer);

            //add data to map
            titleProcessIdMap.put("title", windowTitle);
            titleProcessIdMap.put("pid", String.valueOf(pointer.getValue()));
            titleProcessIdMap.put("rect", rect);
            return titleProcessIdMap;
        }
```

Suppose the "active window" is a Word Document, I need a way of identifying that it is a Word document and getting the filepath/location of the opened Word document in the system.

Comment: you not say what you have as input. you have file handle (if yes - task is trivial) or what ? and no any sense parse *Handle* utility output. need instead code this yourself

Comment: I am asking what I would require as input and any libraries I could use to get this done. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: unclear what you try get. what is you have as input (at begin) what you want get from this

Comment: *file opened in Windows* - what this mean ? which file ? in system opened at once huge count of files. what concrete file you mean ?

Comment: If you get the command line arguments of the running process, you should be able to parse it to get the file name. `word.exe <path to doc>` -> `argv[1]` is what you are looking for

Comment: @RbMm I added the code I have now. Thank you so much for you time.

Comment: @SaileshD Could you kindly explain what you mean by getting command line arguments of the running process? Do you mean the process ID? Because the process ID only gives the path to the program executable.

Comment: @SaileshD --UPDATE-- Your solution worked. I am able to extract file location from the command line arguments. Thank you :)